# C Linked List - understending, how to delete the same element on list

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, function-pointers

Can someone tell my, how it's possible, that this function is working ?
This is my structure :

```
struct el{
    int key;
    struct el *next;
};
typedef struct el elListy;
typedef elListy *list;
```

And this is function:

```
void delete(list *l, int zm)
{
    list p, *k;
    k = l;
    while ((*k))
    {
        if ((*k)->key == zm) {
            p = *k;
            *k = (*k)->next;
            free(p);
        }
        else
        {
            k = &(*k)->n;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can illustrate it, will be awesome.

Comment: Do not `typedef` pointers. It makes it hard to tell what is a pointer and what is a double pointer. Also, add braces to the `while` block, it's really confusing as it is.

Comment: Rather than making us explain the code line by line it would be best if you can tell us what specifically you don't understand. And have you walked through the code in a debugger or even on paper?

Comment: Yes, I walked trough the code using debugger and paper, my problem is to understand, how here pointers are working.

Comment: I don't think this is the real code. Don't use single characters as specifiers, you can't be that lazy since your editor very likely helps you with it's autocompleter.

Comment: Yes, this is real code from study, but everything's hard in the beginning. In this example, the hardest are still pointers.

Comment: what is the meaning for `el`, `elListy`, `zm`, `k` etc? First thing you need to do is to rename everything to something meaningful, and it will help you to understand with a lot less effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tried it, but I'm happy to help you. Let's take a look. As other users suggest, double typedef is really annoying; code isn't clear at all and it's more complex to understand what this code do. The struct composition is about a key, a label, and a pointer to the next struct. The function `delete()` is comparing his `int zm`, which takes it as argument, with any node of the linked list. The second argument is the linked list root pointer, or the start pointer.

About the function:
In words, the function is reading any value (key) of the linked list and comparing it to the int zm. If key is different, (*k) will be the next pointer. This method permitts to read every node from the starting node argument. Take care in the last line where `n` should be `next`.

If key and zm are equals, the function free the node of the list with the `free()` function (because linked list node are usually build with malloc or calloc function) and set that the value of k - which is a double pointer and (*k), the value of the first pointer, is also a pointer - point to the next one, in order to check next node and delete it if needed.

In particular, if zm is equals to the key, the function:

- saves the value of the pointer in the p variable;
- set that k points to the next struct, because the while condition is configured on the k value and it is possible to find 2 or more nodes with the same key;
- free the correct memory pointed by p;

It is important to focus on two things:
1) setting that the k values points to the next struct is important because prevents the code to not stop to the first value it finds.
2) the while condition, (*k), means you are checking the value of k, which is a pointer, until it is NULL, which means the end.

Hope it's clear enough, I'm here for other help.

Answer (score -1):

AT YOUR OWN RISK!!!

```
// sory i have chaged the names, this will make it litle bit clearer

typedef struct elment elment, *p_elment;

typedef p_elment *list;

struct elment{
    int         key;
    p_elment    next;
    p_elment    prev; // you will need it;
};


void delete(list *l, int zm) {

    p_elment    k,p;

    k = (p_elment) *l; // cast to avoid warnings

    while (k){
        p = k;
        k=k->next;

        if (p->key == zm) {

            if (*l == p) 
                  *l=p->next;

            if(p->prev)
                p->prev->next = p->next;

            if(p->next)
                p->next->prev = p->prev;

            free(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `elment`? Make sure you have correct spelling if you are trying to make thing clearer

Comment: well, actually no.  and your change in logic seems flawed too: if it is the first node to be removed, `l` is not updated accordingly and it lost the reason to pass the ptr-to-ptr-to-node as input param.

Comment: so you are 1. not illustrating the original code of OP, 2. not cleaning up the original code to make it easier to understand (as the whole logic changed), 3. your new logic is flawed.  Sorry I cannot assume your answer to be relevant

Comment: it is better but still you are : 1. not illustrating the original code of OP, 2. not cleaning up the original code to make it easier to understand (as the whole logic changed)